# Vogel Distribution 3D javascript

Tags: javascript, python, code-translation

I've been trying to translate [this amazing tutorial](http://blog.marmakoide.org/?p=1), from Python to Javascript. I have no experience with Python, but I made the 2D translation work, is the 3D I'm having trouble with. Not sure how to properly translate the ***numpy.linspace*** function and the ***numpy.sqrt vector*** operation into javascript. So far this is what I got. Thanks a lot in advance

```
 function buildSphere() {
  var n = 246;
  var sphereR = 300;
  var theJSON = [];

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){

    theJSON[i].coordinate = new mo.Point3D(0,0,0);
    var goldenAng = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
    var theta = i * goldenAng;
    var z = (1-1.0/n, 1.0/n-1, n);    
    var r = (Math.sqrt(1-i)*sphereR) * Math.sqrt(z);

    theJSON[i].coordinate.x = r * Math.cos(theta);
    theJSON[i].coordinate.y = r * Math.sin(theta);
    theJSON[i].coordinate.z = z ;

  }
}
```

the Python code I'm translating is this:

```
n = 256

golden_angle = numpy.pi * (3 - numpy.sqrt(5))
theta = golden_angle * numpy.arange(n)
z = numpy.linspace(1 - 1.0 / n, 1.0 / n - 1, n)
radius = numpy.sqrt(1 - z * z)

points = numpy.zeros((n, 3))
points[:,0] = radius * numpy.cos(theta)
points[:,1] = radius * numpy.sin(theta)
points[:,2] = z
```

Any light shed is immensely appreciated, again thanks!

Comment: You might want to tell us what is not working?

Comment: Not entirely sure how to properly translate the numpy.linspace function and the numpy.sqrt vector operation into javascript